# Mag 2.0 - How to display product quantity in stock on storefront

Tags: magento-2.0, frontend, inventory

I need to display the stock quantity for a product in both the category listing and product detail pages. I know which templates to edit, but I don't know how to get the stock quantity passed into the template. Any guidance appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by 'stock quantity'?

Comment: Could you please update your question with the code you've tried, and any errors you've seen. Read up on [how to ask a question here](http://magento.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: By stock quantity, I mean the quantity of the product currently available for sale (from cataloginventory_stock_item table).

Comment: Danny, I haven't tried anything yet, other than adding 'echo $_product->getQty()' to  templates/product/view/type/default.phtml whix displays nothing, but doesn't return an error - I'm not sure what to try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/type/default.phtml I am able to get the stock quantity for an item by using this :

```
$_product->getExtensionAttributes()->getStockItem()->getQty();
```